# Onchange providerlistener function returns loading state alone

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using provider listener to get the state value and then return a snackbar when state has error or navigate to another page when the state has completed value.
Here is my ui

```
return ProviderListener<LoginState>(
   provider: loginControllerProvider,
   onChange: (BuildContext context, value) {
   if (value.loginStatus == Status.COMPLETED) {
      print('redirect');
   }
   if (value.loginStatus == Status.ERROR) {
       print('error');
 } 
 if (value.loginStatus == Status.LOADING) {
     print('loading');
 } 
},
```

My provider

```
 final loginControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<LoginController, 
 LoginState>(
    (ref) => LoginController(ref.read));
```

My statenotifier

```
class LoginController extends StateNotifier<LoginState> {
  LoginController(this._read) : super(LoginState.initial());

  final Reader _read;

  void login(String email, String password) async {
      state = state.copyWith(loginStatus: Status.LOADING, isAuthenticated: false);
      final response = await _read(authRepositoryProvider).doLogin(email, password);
      if (response is AppException) {
          state = state.copyWith(
             loginStatus: Status.ERROR,
             error: response.toString(),
             isAuthenticated: false);
      } else {
          state = state.copyWith(loginStatus: Status.COMPLETED, isAuthenticated: true);
   }
 }
}
```

my loginstate

```
enum Status { INITIAL, LOADING, COMPLETED, ERROR }

class LoginState extends Equatable {
  final Status loginStatus;
  final String? error;
  final bool isAuthenticated;

  LoginState(
    {required this.loginStatus, this.error, required this.isAuthenticated});

     factory LoginState.initial() {
       return LoginState(loginStatus: Status.INITIAL, isAuthenticated: false);
    }

    LoginState copyWith(
       {required Status loginStatus,
       String? error,
       required bool isAuthenticated}) {
       return LoginState(
       loginStatus: loginStatus,
       error: error,
       isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated);
    }

  @override
   List<Object?> get props => [loginStatus, error, isAuthenticated];
 }
```

lastly the function that calls the login method

```
onTap: () => context
                        .read(loginControllerProvider.notifier)
                        .login(emailEditingController.text,
                            passwordEditingController.text),
```

The issue is even though the state in the login method is actually changing, the onchange method only returns the print loading statement even if has error or not.

Comment: You have to actually return a widget from `onChange` I believe. Try returning a `Text` instead of printing.

Comment: returning a widget actually does the same. It only returns the state when loading